# glibc and SSE functionality

Tags: c, performance, sse

I am trying to find information on glibc and to what extent it uses SSE functionality.

If it is optimized, can I use it out-of-the-box?

Say I am using one of the larger Linux distros, I assume that its glibc is compiled to be as generic as possible and to be as portable as possible, hence not optimized?

I am particular interested in the functions memcpy and memcmp and how to get these functions as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

glibc 2.8 does not use SSE for memcpy or memcmp at all(in x86 or x86_64)  - it uses some hand-written assembly which avoids anything not supported on all CPUs of the family. In glibc 2.10, a new type of relocation, [STT_GNU_IFUNC](http://udrepper.livejournal.com/20948.html) will be supported, which will make better optimizations based on CPU support possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile with the highest optimization settings, memcpy and memcmp might be replaced with intrinsics by the compiler and never call glibc at all.  Then the *mcpu* and *march* compiler options will select the fastest code.